# Wordpress site protection with unique password for every user

Tags: database, wordpress, password-protection, multiple-users

How can we develop a voting website based on `Wordpress` where the landing page is `login and password protected` and logins and passwords are based on a `preloaded database` of users. The idea is to create a page for employees where they can enter after they provide the individual credentials. It cannot be based on a system where they register - their data should already be in a database.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you do not want different user roles for different users. If that is the case then you will need to create a function in your theme's **functions.php** file that will check if user is logged in using `is_user_logged_in()` and if not, redirect them to login page. In order to work around the problem of every user registering on site by themselves, you can create another piece of code that will iterate user details from a csv file, register them and set each user's password.

The reason for this suggestion/approach:

1. All the users are registered in your WP Users list so your passwords are not easily stolen.
2. You can assign custom user roles and capabilities later down the line if you wish.
3. You can do single or bulk addition of user down the line without redoing the same amount of efforts every time you need to add users.
4. You do not risk breaking the database structure in WP which is decently optimized.

Now do understand that you will need to leverage object caching and work using `pre_get_posts` to manage the large size of site.

Good Luck!!

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I am wondering, trying to keep things as simple as possible, is there any widget that supports this solution? I am not sure I'll manage to implement it in a way you mentioned as I'm at the beginning of my coding path :) But I really appreciate your effort! Have a great day! :)

Comment: [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/) should help you with user import. I will right the code for redirect later tonight and add to this answer. If you are in hurry, it is essentially just an **if condition** something like `if(!is_user_logged_in()) wp_safe_redirect(<PAGE_SLUG>)` added in **loaded** or **head** hook.